# How can I pause one pygame function without pausing others?

Tags: python, pygame

So I have a function (below) that I want to change a variable every 2 seconds. Currently the function works in changing the variable (goblinx) every 2 seconds. The problem is that time.wait causes all functions to pause for 2 seconds. How could I only have the function movegoblin() pause.

```
def movegoblin():
    global goblinx
    global gobliny
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        goblinx += 32
        pygame.time.wait(200)
```

Comment: One doesn't need multithreading for this -- event loops with timer support are also well-established technique

Comment: Although Pygame does not have a built-in event loop withtiking support. It is easy to implement one - but more complicated than having a character base class with tiing support. Multi-threading indeed is the wrong thing for this problem.

Comment: Please, don't use multithreading for this...
jsbueno provided the correct answer.

Comment: Ubnfortunetly I havent had time o work on the project lately, but i will try jsbuseno idea when school gets out in 4 days.

Answer (score 4):

The way to go here, is to improve your goblin ?(and other characters) handling in your program from functions to proper classes, so they can have internal states.

Each such class them can have variables which are updated at every game frame, and which trigger an action when the count gets to a value.

This solution is cleanr than adding concurrent threads just for timing accounting, and properly done, can lead to an application design wich will be a bliss to develop, expand and maintain.

A short example of the style you could adopt, preserving the functionality in your code.
(Note that you can use the pygame.sprite.Sprite classes to have the "update" method called authomaticaly for each object group - I will do it from scratch bellow)

frame_delay = 20

```
class Goblin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 #or whatever
        self.y = 1 #or whatever
        self.movement_count = 0
        self.move_at_each = 10

    def move(self):
        self.movement_count += 1
        if self.movement_count < self.move_at_each:
            return
        self.movement_count = 0
        self.x += 32
```

In your main loop, you instantiate a goblin doing:

`goblin = Goblin()`, before entering the while loop, and call  `goblin.move()` at each frame.
This way you can have a proper goblin class, which will allow you to have multiple "goblins" in your game - while the code on your example would require you to hard code each character. And you simply call the "goblin.move" method at each frame of your game. The example above is tunned to move each 10 frames, but you can change that (and can change that for each individual goblin you instantiate).

As I said, pygame offers the "Sprite" and "sprite groups" classes as a framework for this kind of mechanics already, but rolling your own in a some smaller game will help you to understand better the needs and what pygame sprites already offer, so you can use them in later projects (or a later stage of this project)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest answer:

Call a .update() function on your goblin each frame. If time elapsed >= 200 ms, then move him. else do nothing.

```
class Unit():
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_delay = 200
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        # call once per game update.
        now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if now - self.last_update >= self.update_delay:
            self.last_update = now

            # update AI , pathfind , etc.
            self.x += 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer that most people will come to mind there first would be something like: "You are thinking the wrong way!" -- which is actually true if you follow the traditional gamedev approach; jsbueno and monkey showed you, how you would normally go there.

I just want to point to a python project, that tries to give a solution in the way you got to the problem. The claim is: the real world is concurrent, so you should model it in a concurrent way (the fact that your intuitive approach was the concurrent one, supports this).

The problem is, that using a real multithreaded approach on the problem will definitely give you more problems than it will solve, since you'll have to think of race conditions etc. (hence the mutex in sajattack's answer). Also the overhead for hundreds of threads if you have hundreds of sprites/objects in your game (which is not a high number, think tens of thousands there if you want to start thinking big) will most likely be overkill for the poor computer handling it.

That's why some folks started a project called [stackless python](http://www.stackless.com/). They wanted to give a tools that lets you program in a concurrent way *without* multithreading! With that you can program like you suggested, having one function waiting, while others continue to run. The concept behind that they call *microthreads* There is also a pretty good article giving you an [introduction to concurrent thinking in programming](http://www.grant-olson.net/python/intro-to-stackless-python/browsable-html). You might want to take a look into that project, but that could leave you with several problems:

1. You'll need a different version of the python interpreter. Stackless is not in standard c-python nor pypy, and most likely won't be any time soon.
2. The fact that you use a different interpreter will make it more difficult to distribute any game written in stackless python.
3. You might learn an uncommon way of game programming -- which might be important in some time in the future (or maybe not). Could give you problems when talking to real life programmers or when reading existing games' sources. It's possibly a good idea to do some *classic* game programming first or in addition to stackless.

Answer (score -1):

```
import _thread    
_thread.start_new_thread(movegoblin, ())
```

or if you prefer

```
import threading
threading.Thread(target=movegoblin).start()
```

with locks:

```
mutex = _thread.allocate_lock()
def movegoblin():
    global goblinx
    global gobliny
    x = 1
    if x == 1:
        mutex.acquire()
        goblinx += 32
        pygame.time.wait(200)
        mutex.release()
```

Comment: After adding the thread, It causes the variable to increase uncontrollably, and the other function to change seldom. after a few seconds I get an error `error: can't start new thread` I have never used threading before so Im not sure what to do. @sajattack

Comment: If you're calling it multiple times you have to make sure the threads aren't overlapping eachother with a lock. Add `mutex = _thread.allocate_lock` globally somewhere and `mutex.acquire()` and `mutex.release()` before and after `goblinx += 32`

Comment: Also, if you're not using python 3, _thread is simply thread.

Comment: All right I added all those changes and keep getting a constant stream of `Unhandled exception in thread started by <function movegoblin at 0x02B0CB30> ` in the shell @sajattack

Comment: Maybe you're not giving goblinx a value before trying to increase it? It works for me.

Comment: I am sorry, but adding threads will just make the terrible design on the example in O.P. even worse. There are ways they could be nice in a game, but implemented inside a proper framework - maybe just a second thread to group all  "A.I." decisions. Either way, one would loop and update all game characters in that other thread - not add a  thread per charater - that is not what threads are for.

Comment: I just gave them what they asked for, a way to pause a function without interrupting the rest of their program.